# Why can't the denominator be rationalized for such a result?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, code

The root formula of the output is rational for denominator, and the result of [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) output is the same.

```
(3 * Sqrt[195] )/10 // FullSimplify
```

changes

```
(3 * Sqrt[39/5] )/2 // FullSimplify
```

The result remains the same.

How to get this result:

```
(3 * Sqrt[195] )/10
```

Comment: **The result remains the same.** what is the output that you expect/want?

Comment: What MMA considers simple is built into MMA. If you try to go against MMA, it will only lead to troubles. (Nevertheless, for completeness, I mention that there is the option "ComplexityFunction")

Comment: The general result is 3 Sqrt(195)/10

Comment: f you type `3 Sqrt[195]/10` as input, you will notice that Mathematica replies with `3 Sqrt[39/5]/2` automatically. Mathematica does many automatic simplifications like these. screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSRfl.png). It likes to simplify fractions and `3/2` is simpler than `3/10` I think these automatic simplifications are done by the frontend/input parser and not by the Kernel.

Comment: @Nasser no, it is done during evaluation, consider `Hold[3 Sqrt[195]/10]`.

Comment: @Kuba but isn't `Hold` just tells the front end not to touch the input or change it in any way before sending it to the kernel? So how would one know for sure if this re-writing is done by kernel or the front end? But at the end of the day, this is one of those automatic simplification that Mathematica does. Fighting it is a losing battle.

Comment: @Nasser no, it is not FE's job. You can Evaluation>NotebooksKernel>LinkSnooper to see: `FE ---> K: EnterExpressionPacket[MakeExpression[BoxData[RowBox[{"3", RowBox[{RowBox[{"Sqrt", "[", "195", "]"}], "/", "10"}]}]], StandardForm]]`

Comment: I added the OP's comment into the question and formatted a bit, but I still don't understand  what kind of answer is the OP expecting. @csn899 please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: This is what it means

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you want to get. Do you want the expression to stay in the following form: (3 * Sqrt[195] )/10? Or what? The second question is even more essential: What is your aim? That is, what for do you want to transform this expression into a specific form? Indeed, if you are going to make further calculations with it, you do not need to transform it. Just go ahead. If it is a final result and you need it for a report, talk, to show it during a lesson, etc. It is easier just to write it as you want it using `HoldForm`. Just try `HoldForm[(3 * Sqrt[195] )/10]`.

Comment: To clarify (or murkify, as the case might be). The autoevaluations are not specifically intended as "simplest" forms. Rather they are an attempt to get a (pardon the oxymoron) semi-canonical form. This is helpful for a number of purposes in terms of speeding internal operations such as `Plus/Times/Power`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to make a form that does this for you:

```
MakeBoxes[a_Rational Power[b_Rational, Rational[1, 2]], fmt_] := With[
    {out = a / Denominator[b], in = Numerator[b] Denominator[b]},
    MakeBoxes[out Power[in, 1/2], fmt]
] /; $RationalizedForm

MakeBoxes[RationalizedForm[x_], fmt_] := Block[{$RationalizedForm = True},
    MakeBoxes[x, fmt]
]
```

Then:

```
RationalizedForm[3 Sqrt[39/5]/2]
```

> (3 Sqrt[195])/10